# sending NSNumber *_ strong to parameter of incompatible type of float

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, viewdidload

Trying to save the position of a Slider:

saving my slider value with NSUserDefaults:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value] forKey:@"slider"];
```

in my ViewdidLoad method:

```
 NSNumber *sliderValue =   [defaults objectForKey:@"Slider"];
[slider setValue:sliderValue];
```

under my setValue method I receive the error: sending NSNumber *_ strong to parameter of incompatible type of float.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of `UISlider`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
[slider setValue:sliderValue];
```

needs to be:

```
[slider setValue:[sliderValue floatValue]];
```

The `value` property of `slider` is of type `float`. You can't simply pass an `NSNumber` reference.

BTW - `NSUserDefaults` has direct support for `float` values:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setFloat:slider.value forKey:@"slider"];

slider.value = [defaults floatForKey:@"slider"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad,

Instead of :

```
NSNumber *sliderValue =   [defaults objectForKey:@"Slider"];
```

write:

```
float sliderValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Slider"] floatValue];
```

`setValue` takes `float` as parameter, while you are providing it `NSNumber`, so it is raising error.